# C# Converting a 1bit BMP to version 3.0

Tags: c#, bitmap, image-conversion

I currently have a C# project given to me that requires the converting any image to a 1bit Bitmap Image.

So far so good. The code is working perfectly well.

When the coverted file is sent to another colleague who needs it for a program that I can only guess was coded on the ark it throws this error:

```
resource file res\icon3.bmp is not in 3.00 format
```

How can I get my application to save in a 3.00 format? It's a bit of a head scratcher.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without code (like image saving code) or example image. Better examine your bitmap file byte by byte and compare with the .bmp file format specification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Was a massive schoolboy error on my part! Code was perfect apart from one line which I will add in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

School boy error! Although the conversion code was fine and working perfectly the error was with the image.save! Even though I had a bitmap file - while analysing the header it was a PNG. Very strange. The code was this:

```
 image.Save(newfilename);
```

After some headscratching this solved the problem:

```
 n.Save(newfilename,ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: The [documentation for Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) explains that if no encoder is present it will save the image as PNG. That is probably the case here.